# d3 'call' method not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to animate a bar graph on a web page, and am trying to use the selection.call feature with limited success. I have defined all my enter transitions for the various parts of the graph like so:

```
    var xAxisEnterTransition = function(selection){
        //None
    };
    var bottomBarsEnterTransition = function(selection){
        selection.transition()
            .duration(900)
            .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return maxBarHeight - y(d['without']); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d['without']); });
    };
    var markerLinesEnterTransition = function(selection){
        //None
    };
    var topBarsEnterTransition = function(selection){
        selection.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300; })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return maxBarHeight - y(d['with'] + d['without']); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d['with']); });
    };
    var bubblesEnterTransition = function(selection){
        selection.transition()
            .duration(400)
            .ease('elastic')
            .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300 })
            .attr("r", bubbleRadius);
    };
    var violationTextEnterTransition = function(selection){
        selection.transition()
            .duration(400)
            .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300 })
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1.0)
            .style("fill-opacity", 1.0);
    };
    var severityTextEnterTransition = function(selection){
        selection.transition()
            .duration(400)
            .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 300 })
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1.0)
            .style("fill-opacity", 1.0);
    };
```

So that I have nice, neat, reusable code. When I call these functions, I do so like this, as specified in the d3 documentation:

```
  bottomBars.call(bottomBarsEnterTransition)
            .each("end", function () {
                topBars.call(topBarsEnterTransition)
                .each("end", function () {
                    bubbles.call(bubblesEnterTransition);
                    violationText.call(violationTextEnterTransition);
                    severityText.call(severityTextEnterTransition);
                });
            });
```

And when I do so, the bottomBarsEnterTransition seems to execute correctly on the page, but then the animation just stops. A check with the debugger reveals that an exception has been thrown inside the d3 code itself:

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'call' 
d3.v3.min.js, line 3 character 8323
```

with the call stack revealing that the offending call was kicked off by the first .each method call.

Now, I know I can work around this issue by writing transitions this way:

```
bottomBarsEnterTransition(bottomBars);
```

but I *need* to be able to use the each method so that my transitions execute in the proper order.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this some issue with d3?

**UPDATE:**

The error appears not to be with 'call' at all...if I call each 'call' method on its own line, the graph renders fine, albeit not in the order I need it to. So, it appears to be the 'each' calls that are causing the problem.

Hope that helps provide a little more insight, and thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Looks like it's complaining about `topBars`. Is that something you can use `.call()` on?

Comment: That is what I originally thought too, but topBars is the same kind of object as bottomBars. If you switch them in the code, the exact same thing will happen, except topBars will get drawn before it crashes instead of the bottoms. In fact, if I just call all the 'call' methods sequentially, it works fine--it is the chaining with 'each' that seems to be causing the issue. I have updated above to reflect this.

Comment: I think there's some confusion with the method chaining. It looks like you mean to call `.each()` on the *transition*, but you're actually calling it on the *selection* -- that is, you are invoking the function on each element in the selection.

Comment: Right, selection.call returns the selection, even if the function you’re calling creates a transition. So you can’t call .each("end", function) on a selection. If you want to structure your code this way you probably don’t want to use selection.call, just call your function directly, and have it return the transition.

Comment: Also, beware that transition.each("end", function) calls the function for each element in the transition. So if bottomBars or topBars contains more than one element, you’ll be creating multiple redundant transitions on bubbles, violationText and severityText.

Comment: So I guess what I really need is a way to tack on a simple callback function that doesn't iterate the way 'each' does, but I can't find one after combing the documentation. Does something like that exist, or would I have to use timed delays to make it work?